# How to get info from a website without it opening

Tags: java, youtube, web

I'm am decently new at programming and I was wondering how I would go about getting info from youtube in regards to my channel. I was wondering if it is possible to check if anyone commented on a video and how many subscriptions my page has within the application. Now, I have a general idea of how I would go about doing this but I was wondering if I could grab all of this info without youtube actually opening in my browser.
   Thanks!

Edit- this is entirely for fun and to increase my programming skills with Java. I know youtube analytics would be a million times better for this, but bear with me here.

Comment: You can use Youtube comments API. Check: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Retrieve_comments . Sample Request URL: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/qCj2oN4QD48/comments

Comment: @Chandu You deserve votes up

Answer (score 0):

You have this website with tutorials and examples. https://developers.google.com/youtube/code_samples?hl=pt-PT" target_"blank"

Answer (score 0):

You should learn YouTube analytics. YouTube Analytics lets you monitor the performance of your channel and videos with up-to-date metrics and reports. There's a ton of data available in different reports (e.g. Views, Traffic sources, Demographics). Here you can learn more: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714323

Comment: He is not looking for complex analytics stuff - just to read comment you have google/youtube API

Comment: He is also eager to know about this subscriptions. I think he will be  benefited more if he knows all about his viewers. @SatheeshCheveri

Comment: I'm just looking for something I can put into my program that can read certain important details about my channel without the page physically being opened.

Comment: oh I see. then you need Youtube APIs to do this. @SatheeshCheveri you were right. I got it wrong.